# Is the last digit of this number :$ {{4^4}^n}+1 $ always $7 $ for $n>1$ and could this be prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Some computations in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of[%284%5E4%5En%2B1%29+],n%3D2+to+6) for $n=2,3,4,5 ,6$ showed that the last

digit of this number $ {{4^4}^n}+1 $ for $n>1$  always $7$ .

**My question here** :How do I know if it's last digit always is $7$ ?

**Note**: My Goal is to  know for which values of $n$: $ {{4^4}^n}+1 $ could be prime ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: The prime question is a bit trickier. $4^{4^n} +1 = 2^{2*4^n} +1 = 2^{2^{2n+1}} +1$. This is the $2n+1$-th Fermat number. We only know a few of them to be prime, but the last digit is always 7 except for the first 2 fermat numbers.

Comment: ok, thanks , could you give me a possible values of n to be prime ?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia article for Fermat numbers for all the details you may want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number.

Comment: ok, thanks for that example ,may the problem to know for large n if it can be prime

Comment: It is unknown even if there are more than 5 of them; it's an open research problem to figure out if there are ones for larger n.

Comment: nice  information

Comment: $65537 = 2^{2^4}+1 = 4^8 + 1$ is the largest Fermat prime [known so far](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_%28number%29), but it can't be written as $4^{4^n}+1$...

Comment: for the titled form no known primes at a least for n=1 to 5 ,all them not prime

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true. For $n≥1$, $4^{(4^n)} = 16^{2^{2n-1}}$ is a power of 16.

Since $16^2 = 256 \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$ and $16\cdot 6 = 96 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$, every power of $16$ ends with $6$. Therefore $4^{(4^n)}+1$ always has $7$ as last digit.

Comment: The value $n=4^{4^2}+1=2^{32}+1$ is divisible by the prime $p=641=2^4+5^4=5. 2^7+1$ because $5^4 n=(5.2^7)^4.2^4+5^4=(p-1)^4.2^4+5^4=(p-1)^4.2^4+p-2^4=((p-1)^4-1).2^4+p=16 p^4+64 p^3+96 p^2+17 p$.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to consider $2^{2^4}+1$ instead of $2^{2^5}+1$…

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to toss this in.Unfortunately no known generalization  of the method for factoring F(5) is known.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. This follows because

- $4^r$ is always even, in particular for $r = 4^n$
- $4^r \equiv (-1)^r = 1 \mod 5$ for all even $r$, in particular for $r = 4^n$.

Therefore $4^{4^n} \equiv 6 \mod 10$ for all $n$ and hence $4^{4^n} + 1 \equiv 7 \mod 10$.